# Update AMI ID in launch template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, aws-auto-scaling, launch-template

I have set up an Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Group that is based on a Launch Template using its latest version. The Launch Template uses an AMI. I have also set up a Data Lifecycle Manager that makes a back-up every X hours so that my data is up to date.

How can I "feed" the AMI ID to the Launch Template dynamically so that everything is automatic?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Launch templates are **immutable**. You have to create new versions of your template, and then modify the Auto Scaling group to use the new version.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! Yes, they are indeed immutable but what would work would be to create a new version of the Launch Template as teh Auto Scaling Group uses the latest version. Would that be possible?

Comment: @kiroroki Yes. That's what I wrote.